# Add non app tests to tests that run when executing python manage.py test

Tags: python, django, django-testing

My Django project has a few app each with their respective tests. It also has a `utils` package that has its own tests.

The package `utils` is in a folder at the same level as manage.py and its tests are in a subfolder called tests in files called test_xxx.py

When I run `python manage.py test` Django runs all tests for all the apps in my project but it does not run the tests for the `utils` package. I can run the tests for the `utils` package by running `python manage.py test utils`.

What I would like to do is that tests for utils are also run when I run `python manage.py test` so that single command tests the whole suite for my project. I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation or searching google or here on how to do it. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!!

--- Additional details ---

#### Directory structure

```
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── ...
├── app1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── tests
│        ├── test_views.py
│        └── test_models.py
├── app2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── tests
│        ├── test_views.py
│        └── test_models.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── code.py
    └── tests
         └── test_utils.py
```

#### Command to execute tests

`python manage.py test`

... that executes ...

`nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=app1,app2, utils --cover-html --cover-erase --logging-filter='selenium' --verbosity=1`

And the coverage report shows that all the tests for app1 and app2 have been executed but not the tests for utils

Answer (score 0):

Django uses the `DiscoverRunner` to run your tests harness. As you can see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner

The first option is:

> top_level can be used to specify the directory containing your
>   top-level Python modules. Usually Django can figure this out
>   automatically, so it’s not necessary to specify this option. If
>   specified, it should generally be the directory containing your
>   manage.py file.

Therefore your test should be run by the test harness because are in the same folder of your `manage.py`. Did you add the `__init__.py` in the tests folder?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the problem. I have made sure there is a __init__.py in the directory containing the tests (and also in its parent directory that contains the code for the module). Still `python manage.py test` does not pick up those specific tests :-(

Comment: Is there any chance you can update the question with some more details?

Comment: I have added details about the directory structure, what files are where and the command that executes the tests. Thanks for helping with this!!